# Download one specific file from SFTP server using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I am trying to download only one file using SSH.NET from a server.

So far I have this:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;
...
public void DownloadFile(string str_target_dir)
    {
        client.Connect();
        if (client.IsConnected)
        {
            var files = client.ListDirectory(@"/home/xymon/data/hist");
            foreach (SftpFile file in files)
            {
                if (file.FullName== @"/home/xymon/data/hist/allevents")
                {
                    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(str_target_dir, file.Name)))
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SshConnectionException(String.Format("Can not connect to {0}@{1}",username,host));
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to construct the `SftpFile` with the string `@"/home/xymon/data/hist/allevents"`.

That's the reason, why I use the `foreach` loop with the condition.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `SftpFile` to call `SftpClient.DownloadFile`. The method takes a plain path only:

```
/// <summary>
/// Downloads remote file specified by the path into the stream.
/// </summary>
public void DownloadFile(string path, Stream output, Action<ulong> downloadCallback = null)
```

Use it like:

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(str_target_dir, "allevents")))
{
    client.DownloadFile("/home/xymon/data/hist/allevents", fileStream);
}
```

---

Had you really needed the `SftpFile`, you could use `SftpClient.Get` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets reference to remote file or directory.
/// </summary>
public SftpFile Get(string path)
```

But you do not.

Comment: .NET 4.8 the using will create a 0 byte file if you get an exception during the client.DownloadFile... May not be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if the file exists, you can do something like that...

```
    public void DownloadFile(string str_target_dir)
    {
        using (var client = new SftpClient(host, user, pass))
        {
            client.Connect();
            var file = client.ListDirectory(_pacRemoteDirectory).FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Name");
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(str_target_dir, file.Name)))
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DriveByDownvoter: You really know how to encourage a new fella, don't you? Small wonder he popped in and then popped right back out. I call you out as a lazy coward. A downvote without constructive criticism? Shameful.

Comment: not sure why it was down voted. only thing I notice that's an issue is that _pacRemoteDirectory is not declared. That's not hard to fix.